# How to call a function inside another function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an online store, I am using [paystack payment gateway](https://developers.paystack.co/docs/paystack-inline), in the api, I am trying to run a function inside the payment gateway api but it's not working. Here is the code:

```
payWithPaystack(returnData, amount){
    const binded = this.service.completePayment.bind(this)
    var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
        key: '.......',
        email: this.details.email,
        amount: amount,
        currency: "NGN",
        ref: `ref-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10e13)}`, 
        metadata: {
            custom_fields: [{
                display_name: this.details.firstName+' '+this.details.lastName,
                variable_name: "mobile_number",
                value: this.details.phoneNumber
            }]
        },  
        callback(res){
            console.log(res)                
            binded(res);
        },
        onClose(){
            console.log('window closed');
            this.color='danger'
            this.payDisplay='Transaction closed'    
            this.payClick=false
        }
    });
    handler.openIframe();
}
```

in the service page here is the code

```
completePayment(sentData){
    console.log('enter')
    this.http.post(`${this.ApiURL}payAm.php`, sentData, {headers:this.headers})
    .subscribe(data=>console.log('ok'), error=>console.log(error))
}
```

Now the issue is that the function `completePayment` is calling partially, the console.log is running, but its not sending the http request, pls how can i solve this issue

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: what's the issue your facing?

Comment: Could you provide some logs? How do you decide that it does not work? Maybe you've got some errors or...?

Comment: the issue is that the this.completePayment(res) is not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the `payWithPaystack` method so that it returns a promise:

```
payWithPaystack(amount){
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
            key: '.......',
            email: this.details.email,
            amount: amount,
            currency: "NGN",
            ref: `ref-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10e13)}`, 
            metadata: {
                custom_fields: [{
                    display_name: this.details.firstName+' '+this.details.lastName,
                    variable_name: "mobile_number",
                    value: this.details.phoneNumber
                }]
            },  
            callback(res){
                console.log(res)                
                //RESOLVE promise
                resolve(res);
            },
            onClose(){
                console.log('window closed');
                //REJECT promise
                reject('window closed');
            }
        });
        handler.openIframe();
    });
}
```

Then use the promise that it returns:

```
this.payWithPaystack(amount)
 .then( sentData => {
    console.log('enter', sentData);
    this.http.post(`${this.ApiURL}payAm.php`, sentData, {headers:this.headers})
    .subscribe(data=>console.log('ok'), error=>console.log(error))
}).catch( reason => {
    console.log("rejected: ", reason);
    this.color='danger'
    this.payDisplay='Transaction closed'    
    this.payClick=false;
});
```

Promises are the best way to chain asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the syntax

```
...
payWithPaystack(returnData, amount){
    const binded = this.service.completePayment.bind(this);
    let handler = PaystackPop.setup({
    ....
    callback(res){
      binded(res);
    }
...
```

You can also try to bind the service ref.

Comment: it says bind does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: Okay, my bad I edideted the answer.

Comment: its not fully working, here is the function in service completePayment(sentData){
  console.log('enter')
  this.http.post(`${this.ApiURL}payAm.php`, sentData, {headers:this.headers}).subscribe(data=>console.log('ok'), error=>console.log(error))
 }

Comment: Have you tried bind the service ref as well? ```const binded = this.service.completePayment.bind(this.service);```